# How to add a dropdown list to DataTable - Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, drop-down-menu, datatables

How can I add a dropdown list populated from a database in the last column of the `DataTable` in my Spring MVC application?

> **PROBLEM:** The drop down list is above the table and not inside the table, the drop down list should be on each row.

**MODEL:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myDatabaseTable")
public class DropdownList {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;

    {...getters and setters here...}
```

**VIEW:**

```
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Find" id="goToDetails" />
</div>

<!--Display Table -->
<div class="rows">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <table id="Orders" class="display select">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Model</th>
                    <th>Order</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>DropDown List</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                    <ul class="list-group" id="info-list-box">
                        <li class="list-group-item control-label">
                            <form:select path ="dropdownList" name="selectedCode">
                                <form:option value="" label="-- Select --" />
                                    <c:forEach var="dropdownList" items="${dropdownLists}" >
                                        <form:option value="${dropdownList.id}" label = "${dropdownList.code}"> </form:option>
                                    </c:forEach>
                            </form:select>
                        </li></ul></table>
                    </div>
               </div>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index() { 
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");

        List<DropdownList> dropdownList = (List<DropdownList>) dropdownListRepo.findAll(); 

        model.addObject("dropdownLists", dropdownLists);
        model.addObject("dropdownList", new DropDownList());
        model.setViewName("index");
        return model;
        }
```

> **NOTE:** When I use the `<tbody>` tag in code above, I get a DataTable error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined`.

Comment: Where is your <table>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you're not producing valid `table` markup. If what you want is for the `select` to be in the last cell of each row you'll need to add a row (`tr`) to the table body (`tbody`), a collection of 4 cells (`td`) to the row (to match the columns within the table head (`thead`)) and then add the `select` to the last cell. If what you're populating the `select` with is the same for each and every row then it might be better to have it as a `render` function for the last column. As long as the markup is valid html, Datatables should be able to cope. It's not magic but it's not far off ;-).

A working example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/eej9zfr2/) but this is the basic markup:

```
<div class="rows">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <table id="Orders" class="display select">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Model</th>
                    <th>Order</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>DropDown List</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Model #</td>
                    <td>Order #</td>
                    <td>Description #</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="selectedCode">
                            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                            <option value="N">Option N</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm sort of confused as to why you wanted to add an unordered list (`ul`) with the select being the only list item (`li`), perhaps it's something that will be populated with other list items? If so, add it back.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! The data going inside the table is also from the database so when I update with your code first line in Datatable is blank with drop down list in last column and then my data populates below without drop down on each row. I used JavaScript to populate data into the table, is there a JavaScript alternative to use for this? @annoyingmouse

Comment: So the select controls what is displayed?

Comment: 15 items from my database are currently shown in the list @annoyingmouse